# How does OpenClover count branches?

Tags: java, clover

The code:

```
public class Branches {
    public double justOneIf(int a) {
        double result;
        if (a > 0) {
            result = 1.0d;
        } else {
            result = -1.0d;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String switches(int x) {
        String result;
        switch (x) {
            case 0: {
                result = "zero";
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                result = "one";
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                result = "two";
                break;
            }
            default: {
                result = "kill all humans";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int deepIf(int x) {
        int y;
        if (x == 0) {
            y = 1;
        } else {
            if (x > 0) {
                y = 2;
            } else {
                y = 3;
            }
        }
        return y;
    }
}
```

In OpenClover (version 4.4.1) report I got metrics for this class:

```
Code metrics
Branches:6
...
```

Why six branches here? How does clover count it?

Comment: Presumably it doesn't consider the switch a branch. 2 simple branches in the first method, 3 in the final method. Leaving only 1 branch for the `switches` method.

Comment: May be. It's look like just statement "if" used for branches. Previous comment by Michael may be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. It's pretty simple: one "IF" means 2 branches. Just it.

> Branch coverage
>
> Branch coverage (or 'decision coverage') is a code coverage metric
>   that measures which possible branches in flow control structures are
>   followed. Clover does this by recording if the boolean expression in
>   the control structure evaluated to both true and false during
>   execution.